# How to plot random intercept and slope model in R

Tags: r

Hello I have a question about how to **plot** a random intercept and slopes model using nlme in R.  I have (with help of Zuur et al., 2009) figured out how to plot a model with random intercepts, but haven't been able to figure out the code necessary to plot a model with random intercept and slope.

## Code for random intercept model:

```
library(nlme)
#stream order random intercept
df1$fStream.Order <- factor(df1$Stream.Order)

Mlme1.so<-lme(rel.abun ~ WI.ADF.period, random = ~1|fStream.Order, data=df1)
```

## code to plot random intercepts model

```
F0.so<-fitted(Mlme1.so, level=0)

F1.so<-fitted(Mlme1.so, level=1)

I.so<-order(df1$WI.ADF.period); WI.ADF.periods<-sort(df1$WI.ADF.period)

plot(WI.ADF.periods, F0.so[I.so], lwd=4, type="l",ylim=c(5,25), xlim=c(-1,10),ylab="Relative Abundance",xlab="WI")
for (i in 1:5){
x1.so <- df1$WI.ADF.period[df1$Stream.Order == i]
y1.so <- F1.so[df1$Stream.Order == i]
K.so <- order(x1.so)
lines(sort(x1.so), y1.so[K.so], type="l")
}
```

Resulting plot shows the fitted line obtained by fixed component (thick line) and random intercept regression lines (thin lines), see Fig 5.2 on page 108 of Zuur et al. (2009) - "Mixed Effects Models and Extensions in Ecology with R"

I would like to make a similar plot of the following model, which contains random slope effect in addition to random intercept.

```
Mlme2.so<-lme(rel.abun ~ WI.ADF.period, random = ~1 + WI.ADF.period | fStream.Order, data=df1)
```

How must I modify code using plot() function above to create a plot showing the random intercepts with varying slopes?

For reference, I would like to make a plot similar to Fig 5.3 on page 111 of Zuur et al. (2009) - "Mixed Effects Models and Extensions in Ecology with R"

Below is sample data used in the models:

```
WI.ADF.period   Stream.Order    rel.abun
8.73    1   8.89
8.73    1   61.82
8.73    1   9.49
0.00    1   2.18
0.00    1   57.04
0.00    1   7.52
0.00    2   8.43
0.00    2   0.43
0.00    2   76.7
0.00    2   2.14
0.00    2   1.07
0.00    2   2.92
0.00    2   0.1
0.00    2   90.1
0.00    2   1.04
0.00    2   0.31
7.96    3   37.34
7.96    3   21.75
7.96    3   30.36
7.96    3   8.6
0.00    3   44.25
0.00    3   11.95
0.00    3   16.37
0.00    3   21.68
3.72    3   2.55
3.72    3   22.79
3.72    3   0.17
3.72    3   7.48
3.72    3   21.43
3.72    3   6.46
3.72    3   8.33
3.72    3   3.57
3.72    3   0.17
0.00    3   2.58
0.00    3   16.79
0.00    3   14.35
0.00    3   16.93
0.00    3   3.73
0.00    3   14.49
0.00    3   3.44
0.00    3   0
0.00    3   0
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. This would dramatically increase the probability of getting an answer.

Comment: ... where reproducible means: with sample data, even if these are random numbers.

Comment: @user1904298 Only modification of your code you need is to replace Mlme1.so to Mlme2.so is lines F1.so and F0.so, rest lines are the same. But the problem why you don't see the different slopes for your streams is that slopes have very small variation. You can check it by looking on output of summary(Mlme2.so) and Random effects part where StdDev for WI.ADF.period for sample data is only 0.0026.

Comment: Than you for that very simple fix!  I tried it out on a model with larger variation in slopes and it worked perfectly!